# Leitura XML NFe?

Tags: c#, xml, nfe, textbox

Estou realizando uma leitura de XML de Nfe porém, no momento estou lendo e jogando em um `txt`, porém não consigo ler essas *tags* abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" versao="2.00>
```

Não consigo identificar essas aberturas de node `<?xml` e `?>`, e `nfeProc` e `infNFe` me retorna o *node* vazio.

```
switch (Ler_Xml.NodeType)            
{   
    case XmlNodeType.Element:
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText("<" + Ler_Xml.Name);
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText(">");
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText("<?" + Ler_Xml.Name);
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText("?>");
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.Text:
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText(Ler_Xml.Value);
        break;
    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText("</" + Ler_Xml.Name);
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText( ">");
        txt_display_xml_envio.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine.ToString());
        txt_display_xml_envio.Update();
        break;
}
```

Comment: tente usar serialização, http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms233843.aspx, a noite faço um exemplo com XML da NFe.

Comment: blz cara vlw, vai ser muito extremamente útil serializar quando eu estiver montando a NFe, porém estou tentando ler um arq.xml e mostralo em um textbox só para teste, esta lendo normal e mostrando, porém essas tags acima que especifiquei no post não são apresentadas, eles retornam vazias assim no textbox <nfeProc><NFe><infNFe>, o encoding que vem antes de tudo bem é apresentado.

Comment: teria como o trecho do código que lê o XML e carrega para o textbox?

Comment: editei o post, colei lá em cima o cod. blz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posso não ter entendido bem a sua pergunta, mas se você está usando um `XmlTextReader`, então não tem como voce simplesmente querer interpretar a primeira linha.

Ela é uma linha de cabeçalho que identifica um arquivo como XML e diz qual é o enconding que o leitor deve usar para interpretar os caracteres no arquivo.

Esquece essa linha e vai adiante.

---

De acordo com seus comentários, acho que entendi melhor sua pergunta.
Você está lendo os nós XML, neste caso, são elementos. Os elementos são aqueles que começam uma entrada no XML. Já os atributos estendem os elementos, exemplo:

```
 <Elemento1 atributo1="texto do atributo" atributo2="12345">
     <Elemento2>Texto do elemento</Elemento2>
 </Elemento1>
```

Com isso, você precisa iterar sobre cada nó para pegar os atributos:

```
foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
{ 
    // Informações do nó (elemento)

    foreach (XmlAttribute att in item.Attributes)
    {
        // informações do atributo
    }
 }
```

Comment: assim certo, o encoding da para esquecer de boa rsrsrs depois só criar denovo o problela é nfeProc e infNFe, elas me retornam <nfeProc> e <infNFe> sendo que deveriam estar assim,<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00"><NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe Id="NFe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" versao="2.00>

Comment: @BrunoPardim atualizei minha resposta. Veja se você consegue entender bem. Mas como já comentado nas outras respotas, eu também uso o XSD da microsoft para gerar as classes automaticamente para leitura e gravação de XML.

Comment: Exato cara, ótima ajuda ! é exatamente isso.

Answer (score 10):

O melhor caminho para trabalhar com NFe, é usar a serialização e deserialização de objetos. 
Mas para que possamos deserializar os XMLs de uma NFe, precisamos primeiramente criar as classes conforme os schemas XML, que podem ser baixados no próprio portal da [NFE](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8=).
Após baixar, basta gerar as classes com o seguinte comando

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe" /c /edb /l:CS /n:PL_008d xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd consReciNFe_v3.10.xsd consSitNFe_v3.10.xsd consStatServ_v3.10.xsd enviNFe_v3.10.xsd inutNFe_v3.10.xsd leiauteConsSitNFe_v3.10.xsd leiauteConsStatServ_v3.10.xsd leiauteInutNFe_v3.10.xsd leiauteNFe_v3.10.xsd procInutNFe_v3.10.xsd procNFe_v3.10.xsd retConsReciNFe_v3.10.xsd retConsSitNFe_v3.10.xsd retConsStatServ_v3.10.xsd retEnviNFe_v3.10.xsd retInutNFe_v3.10.xsd tiposBasico_v3.10.xsd ./nfe_v3.10.xsd
```

Isso irá gerar um arquivo `nfe_v3_10.cs` que deverá ser adicionado em seu projeto.

Feito isso, seremos capazes de deserializar um XML em um objeto.

Para deserializar um XML, basta usar a classe XmlSerializer conforme o trecho a seguir.

```
TEnviNFe myObject;
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TEnviNFe));
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("nfe.xml", FileMode.Open);
myObject = (TEnviNFe)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

Para saber qual classe utilizar no `cast` do comando `Deserialize` que você irá utilizar na hora de deserializar, basta olhar a primeira tag do seu XML, nesse caso, usei um exemplo de um XML de envio da nota que começa com a tag `enviNFe`

Comment: Detalhe importante: no último arquivo coloque .\ antes do nome, por exemplo `.\nfe_v4_00.xsd`. Devido à um bug no `xsd` isto fará que o arquivo final seja `nfe_v4_00.cs`. Fonte: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab41df8-69d4-44e4-8795-436088f230e2/xsdexe-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified?forum=xmlandnetfx&prof=required)

Answer (score 4):

Já pensou em usar o **xsd.exe** pra gerar classes a partir dos XSD's do Schema da Receita?

Meu sistema todo de emissão de NFe é baseado nessas classes, funciona muito bem..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: é exatamente esse o caminho, usa o xsd.exe para gerar as classes com base nos schemas da receita, depois é só seralizar e deserializar os objetos

Comment: @pedroluz eu baixei os esquemas XML do site da receita no seguinte [link](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/listaConteudo.aspx?tipoConteudo=/fwLvLUSmU8=) . Vieram 20 arquivos. Eu preciso passar todos eles como parâmetro para o comando xsd.exe ? Tentei fazer isso, mas ele tenta gerar um arquivo cujo nome é o nome de todos os 20 arquivos concatenados, então ele retorna o erro que o nome do arquivo é grande demais e não pode ser gerado.

Comment: @Rafael, verdade, oq eu fiz eh renomear todos eles pra nomes pequenos, tipo 1.xsd, 2.xsd e assim por diante e chamar pra esses nomes.

Comment: @Rafael, no último arquivo coloque .\ antes do nome, por exemplo `.\nfe_v4_00.xsd`. Devido à um bug no `xsd` isto fará que o arquivo final seja `nfe_v4_00.cs`. Fonte: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab41df8-69d4-44e4-8795-436088f230e2/xsdexe-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified?forum=xmlandnetfx&prof=required)

Answer (score -1):

Quanto ao nome do xsd, retira do comando postado na geração da classe o comando que cria o nome **/n:PL_008d**. Segue a versão NFe 4.00

Não foi necessário alterar o nome dos arquivos.

Copiei o xsd.exe para a mesma pasta onde estão os xsd.

> xsd /c /edb /l:CS xmldsig-core-schema_v1.01.xsd consReciNFe_v4.00.xsd consSitNFe_v4.00.xsd consStatServ_v4.00.xsd enviNFe_v4.00.xsd inutNFe_v4.00.xsd leiauteConsSitNFe_v4.00.xsd leiauteConsStatServ_v4.00.xsd leiauteInutNFe_v4.00.xsd leiauteNFe_v4.00.xsd procInutNFe_v4.00.xsd procNFe_v4.00.xsd retConsReciNFe_v4.00.xsd retConsSitNFe_v4.00.xsd retConsStatServ_v4.00.xsd retEnviNFe_v4.00.xsd retInutNFe_v4.00.xsd tiposBasico_v4.00.xsd ./nfe_v4.00.xsd