# Desencapsulamento do XML da NFe

Tags: c#, xml, nfe, objetos

Pois bem, estou tentando fazer a leitura para importação dos `XMLs` das Notas Fiscais Eletrônicas e estou tendo muita dificuldade em desencapsular o `ICMS` das benditas.

Sem problemas para chegar até o objeto `ICMS`:

```
object objeto = ListaItens[i].imposto.Items[0]
```

Isso retorna um objeto do tipo `TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS` e aqui está a descrição dessa classe:

```
public partial class TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS {

    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS00", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS10", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS10))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS20", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS20))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS30", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS30))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS40", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS40))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS51", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS51))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS60", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS60))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS70", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS70))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMS90", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS90))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSPart", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSPart))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN101", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN101))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN102", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN102))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN201", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN201))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN202", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN202))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN500", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN500))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSSN900", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSSN900))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ICMSST", typeof(TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSST))]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

O que gostaria de fazer é varrer todas os "tipos" de `ICMS` para pegar suas propriedades, mas não achei forma alguma de fazer um loop `for` desencapsulando cada elemento.

Podem ajudar?

**`EDIT:`**

Uma coisa que percebi na prática (não tenho lá grandes conhecimentos fiscais) é que cada item no `XML` vai apresentar apenas uma dessas classes de `ICMS` encapsuladas, portanto só precisaria achar um jeito do programa fazer o `unbox` do objeto escolhendo em tempo de execução a classe contida. Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

**`EDIT2:`**

Faço a deserialização da seguinte forma:

Tenho uma classe `Serializer`:

```
public static class Serializer
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(this XElement xElement) 
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xElement.ToString())))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }
        }

        public static XElement Serialize<T>(this object o)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, o);
                    return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

E uma classe `ProcNFe_v3_10` gerada à partir do `.xsd` que peguei no site da fazenda (não vou postar por ser muito extenso).

Então primeiramente eu carrego um `XElement` com meu `.xml`:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(ofdXml.FileName);
```

Sendo `ofdXml` um `OpenFileDialog`.

E posteriormente chamo o método `deserializer` da minha classe passando `TNfeProc` como tipo `T` (que é o tipo correspondente da minha nota, contida dentro da classe `ProcNFe_v3_10`) e o `xElement` carregado como atributo, da seguinte forma:

```
TNfeProc NFCarregada = Serializer.Deserialize<TNfeProc>(xElement);
```

E voilà, tenho meu `XML` deserializado.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44130/leitura-xml-nfe?rq=1

Comment: Na verdade @HStackOverflow, eu já estou utilizando a deserialização do `XML` a partir do schema original da NFe. Meu problema é chegar até essa informação em específico. O restante dos dados já consegui extrair.

Comment: Está fazendo deserialização? Tem como postar o código?

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Editei a pergunta adicionando a deserialização.

Comment: Pode ser com LINQ?

Comment: Será um ótimo momento para eu aprender a trabalhar com LINQ. Manda ver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aí vai uma solução:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = "c:\\temp\\arquivo.xml";
        var nfe = XElement.Load(fileName);
        var nfeCarregada = Serializer.Deserialize<TNfeProc>(nfe);

        var imp = nfeCarregada.NFe.infNFe.det.Select(x => x.imposto);
        foreach (var imposto in imp)
        {
            if (imposto.PIS.Item.GetType().Name == "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT")
            {
                var pisNT = (TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISNT)imposto.PIS.Item;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("PISNT: \nCST:{0}",  pisNT.CST));
            }
            else if (imposto.PIS.Item.GetType().Name == "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq")
            {
                var pisAliq = (TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoPISPISAliq)imposto.PIS.Item;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("PISAliq: CST:{0}\nvBC:{1}\nvPIS:{2}", pisAliq.CST, pisAliq.vBC, pisAliq.vPIS));
            }//CONTINUA

            if (imposto.COFINS.Item.GetType().Name == "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoCOFINSCOFINSNT")
            {
                var cofins = (TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoCOFINSCOFINSNT)imposto.COFINS.Item;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("COFINS: \nCST:{0}", cofins.CST));
            }//CONTINUA

            foreach (var itemImposto in imposto.Items.Select(x => x.Serialize<TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS>()))
            {
                var tipoICMS = itemImposto.Elements().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Name.LocalName;
                if (tipoICMS.ToString() == "ICMS60")
                {
                    var icms = (TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS60)Serializer.Deserialize<TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS>(itemImposto).Item;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CST {0} ORIGEM {1}", icms.CST, icms.orig));
                }
                else if (tipoICMS.ToString() == "ICMS00")
                {
                    var icms = (TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00)Serializer.Deserialize<TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS>(itemImposto).Item;
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ICMS00:\nCST {0} \norig {1} \nmodBC {2} \npICMS {3} \nvBC {4} \nvICMS {5}",
                        icms.CST, icms.orig, icms.modBC, icms.pICMS, icms.vBC, icms.vICMS));
                }//..continua
            }
        }
    }
```

**Resultado:**
[image: Resultado Deserialização NFe]

**Obs:**
Não consigo Deserializar os tipos **"item"** (veja imagem campo CST) caso você consiga pegar os valores destes campos favor compartilhe este código :).

Comment: Cara, parabéns e obrigado pela sua solução. Adicionei ao meu programa e funcionou uma beleza! Vou implementar e tentar resolver o caso o tipo **item**. Apenas me diga, por que fez comparação apenas para `ICMS00` e `ICMS60`?

Comment: Veja que abaixo tem `//..continua` como era apenas um teste não implementei tudo, o correto é comparar com todos. Se resolver o problema do ´item` favor coloque aqui nos comentários. @CassioMilanelo

Comment: Imaginei que fosse isso mesmo, só achei curioso por ser o 00 e o 60, que são os mais corriqueiros no meu caso.

Comment: encontrei uma falha no código: no último `foreach` onde há a leitura do `ICMS`, é feita a serialização de todo o conteúdo de `imposto.Items` passando a classe `TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS` como tipo. O erro acontece quando há outros tipos dentro do objeto, tais como `TIpi`, por exemplo.

Comment: Posta a correção aqui que eu adiciono na resposta, caso não consiga corrigir manda o link pro XML que gera este erro.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei por utilizar um `for` para varrer o conteúdo de `Item` e um `Switch` para selecionar a classe correta (o que me pareceu um serviço bem ruim, por sinal):

```
string porcICMS;
string porcIPI;
for (int j = 0; j < (ListaItens[i].imposto.Items.Length); j++)
{
    switch (ListaItens[i].imposto.Items[j].GetType().ToString())
    {
        case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS": 
            object ICMS = (((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS)(ListaItens[i].imposto.Items[j])).Item);

            switch (ICMS.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS10": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS10)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS20": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS20)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS51": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS51)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS60": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS60)ICMS).vICMSSTRet;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS70": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS70)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS90": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS90)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
                case "TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSPart": porcICMS = ((TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMSPart)ICMS).pICMS;
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case "TIpi":
            object IPI = (((TIpi)(ListaItens[i].imposto.Items[j])).Item);
            porcIPI = ((TIpiIPITrib)IPI).Items[1];
            break;

        default:
            porcICMS = "0.0000";
            porcIPI = "0.0000";
            break;
    }
}
```

Mas funcionou. Em `IPI` há ainda outro objeto `Item` que utilizei o valor `Item[1]`, que corresponde à porcentagem.

Novamente, me aparenta ser um serviço amador o que fiz. Se tiver outra solução, compartilhe-a.

Comment: Posta o link pro XML para eu testar.

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema para serializar o ICMS, depois caiu a minha ficha que o nó `.imposto.Items` pede um `new object[]` então consegui resolver aqui no meu código da seguinte maneira:

```
//Criar os novos objetos de impostos possíveis para o produto!
nfe.infNFe.det[index].imposto.Items = new object[4] { ICMS, II, TIpi, ISSQN };

//Desencapsulando!
nfe.infNFe.det[index].imposto.Items[0] = new TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMS()
{
   Item = new TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00()
   {
     orig = Torig.Item0,
     CST = TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00CST.Item00,
     modBC = TNFeInfNFeDetImpostoICMSICMS00ModBC.Item0,
     vBC = "0.00",
     pICMS = "0.00",
     pFCP = "0.00",
     vFCP = "0.00"
   }
};
```

Espero ter ajudado!