# Namespace Serialization com link

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Estou trabalhando com Serialização, estou adicionando Namespace em duas tags, A nfeProc e NFe. Consigo adicionar normalmente a seguinte Name:

```
[XmlRoot("nfeProc", Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]
```

No XML:

```
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
```

Porém quando tento adicionar o mesmo Namespace no child NFe, não funciona com o mesmo link:

```
XmlElement("NFe", Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]
 public NFe NFe;
```

Resultado:

```
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <NFe>
```

Se eu alterar o link, colocar um espaço antes, depois vou qualquer caracter aparece:

```
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
  <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe ">
                                              **^**
                                             espaço -_-
```

Comment: Por que está reinventado a roda? :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44130/leitura-xml-nfe?rq=1 `O melhor caminho para trabalhar com NFe é usar a serialização e deserialização de objetos.` Outra dica a `versao "2.00"` foi desabilitada este mês, agora é `3.10`

Comment: Pois como disse, estou utilizando serialização, quanto a versão, estou realizando testes gerando o xml, não estou instanciando web service, o problema que tenho é que não consigo colocar um namespace na tag referida.

Comment: rsrsrsr entendi, rsrsrsrs, deste como os xmls eram pequenos usei um stringbuilder para gerar rsrsrsrsr, agora sim estou usando serialização rsrsrsrsrs.

Comment: Verifiquei que não consigo repetir o namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Beleza pessoal, vou postar um exemplo de serialização, com esse recurso consigo montar rapidamente e sem complicação meus xmls.

Uma classe parcial que montei, a partir do layout de uma NFe

importe using System.Xml.Serialization;

Neste exemplo, poderão ver que em cada classe, tem propriedades, propriedades que podem virar tags, ou grupos de tags no xml.

Ex: Abaixo temos a tag root do xml a classe NFe, entro dela temos um grupo filho chamado infNFe, e dentro da mesma temos varias tags, que porém ser classes(que serão grupos no xml) ou propriedades(que serão elementos no xml). Podemos definir atributos para os grupos ou elementos, assim como a ordem

```
//adicionando namespace na tag root
[XmlRoot("NFe", Namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")]  

    public class NFe // tag root no xml
    {

        public infNFe infNFe; // tag grupo filho do root
    }

    public class infNFe
    {


        [XmlAttribute("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; } //essa propriedade é um atributo, neste grupo infNFE, definifo por [XmlAttribute("Id")] acima dele
        [XmlAttribute("versao")]
        public string versao { get; set; } //a mesma explicação acima
        public ide ide; //tag grupo filho do infNFE
        public emit emit;  //tag grupo filho do infNFE
    }

    public class ide
    {   

        [XmlElement(Order = 1)] // esse elemento vai ser o primeiro dentro do grupo ide
        public string  cUF { get; set; }
        public string  cNF { get; set; }
        public string natOp { get; set; }
        public string indPag { get; set; }
        public string mod { get; set; }
        public string serie { get; set; }
        public string nNF { get; set; }


    }

     public class emit{

                  //grupo vazio
       }
```

Depois da classe montada, para podermos montar nosso xml, temos com instanciar cara classe.

Ex:

```
NFe serial_exemplo = new NFe(); //Instanciando o root do xml
serial_exemplo.infNFe = new(); //Depois de instanciar NFe temos acesso a infNFe e instanciamos.

    serial_exemplo.infNFe.Id= "teste"; // setando uma propriedade definida com item na classe ex no xml: <infNFe Id="teste"></infNFe>
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.versao = "teste";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide = new ide(); //tag ide grupo, sua classe tem propriedades para setar(elementos)
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.emit = new emit(); //tag emit grupo


    //propriedades presentes na classe ide que serão elementos no xml.
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.cUF = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.cNF = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.natOp = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.indPag = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.mod = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.serie = "TESTE";
    serial_exemplo.infNFe.ide.nNF = "TESTE";
```

Depois da classe pronta e instancia dela realizada, é necessário serializar a classe e gerar o arquivo.

```
var xml_string = new System.Text.StringBuilder();// crio uma var string 
var internalWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(xml_string); // refenciado a minha stringbuilder para uma StringWriter.
System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(internalWriter); // referencia da StringWriter para writer porém do Writer.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(NFe)); // referencia a classe para o serial
```

//caso um namespace personalizado ex:
   XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
   ns.Add("", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, nfe, ns);// por fim, cria o xml(writer), com base da classe(nfe), namespace no grupo filho da tag root.
```

Agora já se pode criar o arquivo com o conteudo de xml_string.

O final do arquivo será esse:

```
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="teste" versao="teste" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<ide>
<cUF>teste</cUF>
<cNF>teste</cNF>
<natOp>teste</natOp>
<indPag>teste</indPag>
<mod>teste</mod>
<serie>teste</serie>
<nNF>teste<nNF>
</ide>
<emit></emit>
</infNFe>
</NFe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isto que você está tentando fazer não apenas é incorreto como [é fora de padrão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx). Se há `xmlns` definido no elemento pai, todos os filhos pertencem automaticamente ao *namespace*.

A exceção ocorre quando há duas definições de *namespace* no elemento pai, como por exemplo:

```
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" temp:xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
```

Aí você estaria definindo dois *namespaces* possíveis, identificando com um prefixo a qual namespace o elemento filho pertence:

```
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe "></NFe><!-- Usa o namespace http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe -->
<temp:exemplo><temp:exemplo><!-- Usa o namespace http://tempuri.org -->
```

Comment: Blz cara, já estou serializando o xml por completo por uma classe, boa responsta tbm.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor caminho para trabalhar com NFe é usar a serialização e deserialização de objetos. Outra dica a versao "2.00" foi desabilitada este mês, agora é 3.10 @rubStackOverflow

Optei por usar Serialização, apartir de uma classe estruturada gero rápidamente e dinâmicamente um xml.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: Pode colocar também um exemplo de código sobre como ficou sua serialiazação? O objetivo é ajudar mais usuários no futuro. Obrigado!

Comment: blz, sem problemas. vou postar