# Extrair atributos de um XML em uma mensagem SOAP

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, soap

Estou construindo um WebService que retorna status de um objeto, para tanto recebo os dados do objeto para pesquisar na base via mensagem SOAP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:agr="http://site.temp.br/"> 
   <soapenv:Header/> 
   <soapenv:Body> 
      <agr:getObjeto_V1> 
         <arg0> 
            <TipoObjeto>C</TipoObjeto> 
            <CodigoObjeto>999999</CodigoObjeto> 
            <Valor>9999999999999</Valor> 
            <NomeObjeto>xxxxxxxxxxxx</NomeObjeto> 
         </arg0> 
      </agr:getObjeto_V1> 
   </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Esse é a mensagem soap enviada para o webservice, no service eu pego essa mensagem tranquilamente, mas, estou apanhando um pouco para pegar os valores dos nós que estão dentro do nó arg0, estou tentando assim:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(xmlSoapRequest.InnerXml);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Envelope/Body/getObjeto_V1/arg0");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            char TipoObjeto = (char)xn["TipoObjeto"].InnerText[0];
            string CodigoObjeto = xn["CodigoObjeto"].InnerText;
            string valor = xn["Valor"].InnerText;
            string NomeObjeto = xn["NomeObjeto"].InnerText;
        }
```

Como eu posso fazer isso? Se tiver uma outra forma em que eu não precise selecionar os atributos manualmente, mas, fazer a conversão diretamente para uma classe, eu também aceito.

Comment: Não seria uma opção trabalhar com serialização e deserialização do teu Xml https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44245/5846 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13087/5846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste seu caso, eu sugiro que você utilize o [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) para selecionar os nós que deseja. Uma vez que, não é muito trabalhoso manipular XML com ele.

Veja como obter os valores com o LINQ através deste seu XML, segue o código:

```
var xml = @"
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:agr=""http://site.temp.br/"">                 
       <soapenv:Header/> 
       <soapenv:Body>  
        <agr:getObjeto_V1>   
            <arg0>   
               <TipoObjeto>C</TipoObjeto>   
               <CodigoObjeto>999999</CodigoObjeto>   
               <Valor>9999999999999</Valor>   
               <NomeObjeto>xxxxxxxxxxxx</NomeObjeto>   
            </arg0>   
         </agr:getObjeto_V1>
       </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
";            

var objs = (
            from p in XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("arg0")
            select new
            {
                TipoObjeto = (string) p.Element("TipoObjeto"),
                CodigoObjeto = (string) p.Element("CodigoObjeto"),
                Valor = (string) p.Element("Valor"),
                NomeObjeto = (string) p.Element("NomeObjeto")
            }
          ).ToList();

objs.ForEach(x => 
{
    WriteLine($"Tipo objeto: {x.TipoObjeto}");
    WriteLine($"Codigo objeto: {x.CodigoObjeto}");
    WriteLine($"Valor: {x.Valor}");
    WriteLine($"Nome objeto: {x.NomeObjeto}");
});
```

Saída:

> Tipo objeto: C
>   Codigo objeto: 999999
>   Valor: 9999999999999
>   Nome objeto: xxxxxxxxxxxx

Usei o método [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) para retornar os elementos descendentes do elemento especificado, que é o elemento `arg0`, e transformei eles e uma lista que contém uma coleção de objetos de tipo anônimo.

Veja o programa funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/57gBoX).

Comment: Eu acabei resolvendo de outra forma, mas, vou testar a sua e te digo depois.