# Como fazer o a leitura do arquivo xsd de dentro do meu projeto C#

Tags: c#, xml, path, xml-schema

Estou fazendo a validação de um xml a partir de um arquivo xsd dessa forma:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", @"D:\Arquivo\VoltVarPlanning.xsd");

Validate("D:/Arquivo/Exemplo_Saida.xml", schemaSet);
```

porém não quero buscar o o meu arquivo **VoltVarPlanning.xsd** de fora da  minha aplicação, conforme estou fazendo:

```
schemaSet.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", @"D:\Arquivo\VoltVarPlanning.xsd");
```

Por isso coloquei o .xsd dentro do mesmo path do serviço que faz essa validação. Porém não estou conseguindo buscar o **VoltVarPlanning.xsd** no path, ele da erro, por não encontrar o arquivo.

Eu fiz dessa forma, mas não funciona:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", @"\VoltVarPlanning.xsd");

Validate("D:/Arquivo/Exemplo_Saida.xml", schemaSet);
```

Como eu faço para buscar o xsd, sendo que o mesmo já está dentro da minha Solution?

Comment: Veja se essa minha resposta não lhe ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44245/5846

Comment: Não exatamente pois eu só quero validar se o formato do meu xml está de acordo com meu xsd. para isso eu seto o meu **schemaSet** com meu xsd que está nesse path  **schemaSet.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", @"D:\Arquivo\VoltVarPlanning.xsd");**. Porém ao invés de fazer a chamada de meu path **D:\Arquivo\VoltVarPlanning.xsd**, eu quero fazer de dentro da minha própria **Solution**, pois eu já possuo o meu VoltVarPlanning.xsd dentro do mesmo diretório do serviço onde faço essa validação. Não sei se deu pra entender minha dúvida.